# How to print the key and value of an object?

Tags: javascript

I have an object like this

```
var data = {'name':'test','rollnum':'3','class':'10'};
```

I want to console it by iterating through it like,

```
 name:test
 rollnum:3
 class:10
```

Can anyone please help me.Thanks.

Comment: Is there a need for this question?

Comment: @jax No, this is literally one of the first questions on SO. Don't know why people answer it when they can flag or close it.

Answer (score 3):

This will work for values that are Strings or Numbers.

```
var data = {'name':'test','rollnum':'3','class':'10'};

var i;
for (i in data) {
    console.log(i + ":" + data[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With modern JavaScript syntax, this becomes quite elegant:

```
const data = {'name':'test','rollnum':'3','class':'10'};

Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, val]) => console.log(`${key}: ${val}`));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i in data) {
    console.log (i,':', data[i])
}
```